# No Internet connection inside Docker container

Tags: docker

**OS**: Ubuntu 16.04

**Docker version**: 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4

Inside docker containers no Internet connection but I get hosts IPs.

When I run

```
docker run busybox ping -c 3 google.com
```

100% packages lost.
When I run

```
docker run busybox nslookup google.com
```

I get google IP and all works fine.
I get IP from all hosts which ping but packages are lost.

When I run this command

```
docker run --network=host busybox nslookup google.com
```

all works fine.

**I think that problem is with my Internet provider. Because when I use my 3G Internet all works fine and I can ping hosts.**

What I must do for run docker containers with another network?